# Google BigQuery UNION ALL Not Working As Expected

Tags: google-bigquery

This works just fine:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT query
FROM
(SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT query, impressions FROM a_temp.sqpr1) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT query, impressions FROM a_temp.sqpr2) 
)
)
```

This gives an error:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT query
FROM
(SELECT query, impressions FROM a_temp.sqpr1) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT query, impressions FROM a_temp.sqpr2)
```

Specifically, the error is: Queries in UNION ALL have mismatched column count; query 1 has 1 column, query 2 has 2 columns at [6:2]

Both queries clearly have 2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery is parsing your query as:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT query
FROM
(SELECT query, impressions FROM a_temp.sqpr1)

UNION ALL 

(SELECT query, impressions FROM a_temp.sqpr2)
```

not as:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT query
FROM

(SELECT query, impressions FROM a_temp.sqpr1)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT query, impressions FROM a_temp.sqpr2)
```

The parser is seeing `(SELECT DISTINCT query FROM X) UNION ALL (Y)`, not `SELECT DISTINCT query FROM (X UNION ALL Y)`, which is why it's complaining about mismatched column counts: the column counts are mismatched!

The first query with the explicit parenthetical grouping works because it forces the parser to see the query in the latter form, as opposed to the former, which has column counts that match.